# how to get only one value from subquery

Tags: sql

```
select users.name
from(
select users.name, pay.uid, 
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count(pay.uid) DESC) AS ranking
from pay, users
where users.uid = pay.uid
group by users.uid)
where ranking = 1
```

i only want to get users.name output not name,uid,rank.

Comment: alias the query .name isn't referencing users table so its unknown `SELECT sub.name...`  `....GROUP BY users.uid) as sub`   Also... what is pay?  you have tables loans and users defined...  but not "Pay.uid... so is pay and loans the same?  very confusing

Comment: @xQbert loans = pay, i forget to change it, sorry

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sub.name
FROM (SELECT users.name, pay.uid, 
      RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count(pay.uid) DESC) AS ranking
      FROM pay
      INNER JOIN users
        on users.uid = pay.uid
      GROUP BY users.uid) sub
WHERE ranking = 1
```

- alias the inline view (sub)
- change alias on outer select to `sub` instead of `pay`

  - The outer query has no knowledge of the tables inside thus the sub alias.
- avoid using , for joins that's a 1980s technique the newer standars are to use joins (inner, outer (left, right full), cross etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If I read your problem
You can use this query:

```
select table.name
from(select users.name, loans.uid, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY count(loans.uid) DESC) AS ranking from loans left join users on users.uid = loans.uid group by users.uid) as 'table'
where ranking = 1
```